# Justified Tabs do not stick to width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I want to make the Tabs align on the full content. So i am using nav-tabs as you can see in the content below.
It maybe looks a little bit strange since I am using Angular 4 and the code is copied from the Dev Tools.

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified nav-tabs nav-tabs-justified">
    <li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
     <a class="nav-link active" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span _ngcontent-c5="">Artikel</span>
     </a>
    </li><li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>Rezeptierung/Ökonomie</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li><li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>Teilbarkeit</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li><li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>Zusammensetzung</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li><li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>Kurzinformation</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li><li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>ATC/IND</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li><li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>Lagerung/Abgabe</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li><li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>Hersteller</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li><li class="nav-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="nav-item,">
      <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span>Fachinformation</span>
        <!--bindings={}-->
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the Output of this code is pretty normal I think, but only when it is full size. If I am resizing my Page then it looks like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAXDi.png)

On the right side you can see the End of the content and then there is a overflow of the tabs.

Does anybody know how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with jQuery. 
Since i have 9 Tabs overall, i said OK:

`if $(window).width() <= 1473 {
      // ever third li element add a new </ul><ul> Element, so it will create a new line.
   } else {
     // remove </ul><ul> to have the full width.
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap recommended:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Ul tag -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: The difference is, I am not using it in navigation. I am using it in my Html-body.

Comment: Do you have those images on absolute position?

Comment: My parent div has this CSS applied:
.inlineInfo{
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 55vh;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 12.5px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1010;
    border: 5px solid #e7e7e7;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
},

But no i haven't. The images are in a different div outside of the tabs

Comment: Sorry mate but I mean... What kind of css do images have? Maybe they are over due to css styles

Comment: the div in which the img-tag is has just the pull-right-class

Comment: Take a class="cols-...." for each parent div if they are on the same level. Or you can try to giving "with: 100%" for ul tag. Send me the the code if you can't solve it mate!

Comment: it would be enough for me if the tabs would just break and use two lines